# Warning about deleting own answered question

Tags: support, deletion, deleted-questions

I would like to delete my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024590/probability-mathcaln150-30-what-is-p-mathbfx-150-of-four-random) since the problem was due to human error but I am being warned that I could be blocked:
[image]

How serious is the warning? Or can I just proceed without worry?

Comment: I think that if you delete once in a while, it's not a big deal. If you delete your questions often you can find yourself in a question ban, which you may not be able to get out of. But once here and then it's not harmful.

Comment: I don't think (and you should wait for a moderator's word on this) you can be banned for inappropriately deleting just a few questions. If it's too frequent, then that's another matter. In any case you say the question arose from human error, so there's a not so small chance that the question is too localized and as such is not even a good fit for MSE.

Comment: @GitGud it wont let me delete it now.

Comment: @AsafKaragila it wont let me delete it now.

Comment: The (non-)answer was deleted otherwise, it should be possible to delete the question now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a warning meant to make you consider the deletion. So, you should pause to think: does this Q&A pair add any value to the Internet? If your answer is confident *no*, go ahead and delete.

It is true that deleting many own questions is a factor  in automatic question blocks (now rolling time-limits). However, a user with 1000 rep and many well-received posts is unlikely to hit those. You can ignore the second paragraph unless you are on a self-deletion rampage.

Also, note that the system will still block the deletion in the following cases:

1. The question has two or more answers
2. The question has at least one answer with at least one upvote  (it does not have to have a positive net score: e.g., an answer with +1 -2 votes will block deletion).

---

In the specific case, it seems the answer might be removed anyway, since it's downvoted and has drawn a vote to delete. When/if it's gone, you will be able to delete the question.

Comment: I just want to delete since it is from user error not a math issue. However, it now wont let me delete it.

Comment: See my update..